# Can I use Recruit to fill faction based challenges?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

In the daily and weekly(Ubisoft Club) challenges, you sometimes get challenges that require you to win X amount of rounds with an operator from a certain factions (or CTUs).

I recently bough the Started Edition, so I only have a few operators available.

But, if you choose the Recruit, you can choose a faction at the start of the round. (Which dictates the loadouts you choose from.)

Can I just choose Recruit of a certain faction to fill the daily/weekly challenges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer, it seems, is **yes**.

I happened to have a faction/CTU spesific mission in both daily and weekly challenges. Managed to get a game where I won the necesery rounds while I used *only* a Recruit (of the challenge faction).

Once the match was over, both challenges were completed.

You can see the place you need to make the selection in at the picture below.

[image: Recruit's CTU selection menu]

Comment: Yes, I've also managed to do this.

Comment: You can pick any of the base, sadly any operators released after the base ones you can't do.